# Instantiate view controller from within navigation stack on launch

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, segue, appdelegate, xcode-storyboard

I have an app like this

Navigation controller -> login controller -> main view controller -> other stuff

I want to try to login in applicationdidfinishloadingwithoptions, and if that is successful then load main view controller, otherwise load the login view controller. My problem is I want the navigation stack to remain intact like above no matter what, so that I can pop back to my login view controller if I want to log out.

Right now I try to instantiate a main view controller on successful login, but on logout and other navigations it complains that I don't have a navigation controller embedded.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using storyboards then first of all create a `UIViewController` for Login and give it a storyboard ID, second create your mainViewController and embed it in `UINavigationController` and give storyboard id to `UINavigationController`.

After that in AppDelegate.m's `applicationdidfinishloadingwithoptions` load your appropriate VC based on user is logged in OR not.

## Example

```
// Check if user is logged in
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"loggedIn"] == NULL || [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"loggedIn"] isEqualToString:@"false"]) {
        // show login page
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

        UIViewController *mainViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];

        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
} else {

        // show home page
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *mainViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home"];

        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

## Edit

So your stack will become like this

```
NavController->mainVC->OtherStuff
```

And standalone

```
LoginVC
```

Comment: Could you help me with visualizing this? I am thinking of this from your answer (Nav->login->main(w/nav embedded)->other) then give an id to my login and the navigation controller embedded?

Comment: @user3667450 I think the code example is enough to understand OR do you require images?.

Comment: ah! No images won't be necessary but thanks, the code example had not loaded yet when I commented. Thanks! I will try this out right now

Comment: I am confused as to which controllers the storyboard ids are referring to, don't I need to instantiate a navigation controller as root in order to navigate? More along these lines, how do I go back and forth between login and main?

Comment: @user3667450 `home` id is on UINavController and `login` for UIViewController. And yes the Nav Controller should be root when you are showing your main VC, not when you are showing login VC. And  for opening the VC's you will need to open it as a model segue.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. When I want to "logout" and go to my login view controller, how would I add that to my stack? Or will it already be loaded and I am misunderstanding..

Comment: @user3667450 When you do logout either open loginVC as model segue OR make loginVC as rootVC.

Answer (score 1):

Yogesh's answer worked well for me, however I found a more elegant way to carry out exactly what I needed. In applicationdidfinishlaunchingwithoptions I perform a test to log in. If I am logged in (test successful) I do push an instance of my main view controller onto the stack like this.

```
if(loggedIn) {
    UIViewController *main = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main"];
    [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:main animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigation controller -> login controller -> main view controller -> other stuff

Change your Navigation Stack,

Navigation controller - > main view controller -> other stuff

So main view controller is the RootViewController of the navigation stack.

if(userloginstatus == YES)
{

Do other stuff, show other screens based on the flow.

}
else
{

Push or present 'loginviewcontroller' from the main view controller,
  So after successfull login just pop the 'loginviewcontroller'

}